# Adding custom delete button for table view with coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I was wondering how to create a custom button to delete a cell and contents from core data. Instead of having swipe to delete, I would like to have just a button in another view controller that does the same thing as swipe to delete. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a row, you would either reference an existing view controller or create a new one. In either case, you would presumably pass the selected object - an `NSManagedObject` if it represents a core data object - into the new view controller.

Inside that view controller, where you now have a reference to the NSManagedObject that needs to be deleted, you would then have an IBAction method that is associated with the button you are using to trigger deletion. Inside that IBAction you would have something like the following to handle the deletion:

```
- (IBAction)deleteManagedObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObject *objectToBeDeleted = [self managedObject]; // Replace this with whatever you use to reference the managed object
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [objectToBeDeleted managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:objectToBeDeleted];
}
```

This is but one example of a way you can do it. Specifics will vary on how you get the object to be deleted, the managed object context, and whether or not you want to save the changes immediately or later. But this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: So this seems to work but if I then make it navigate back to the other view controller, I get an error saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'TimeTravelFeed''"

Comment: That is a different problem - When you navigate back you are presenting the original view controller. Something in your navigation code is likely calling `[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TimeTravelFeed" inManagedObjectContext:moc` with a `nil` value for the managed object context parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell and add to it a delete button.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath set the tag of the delete button to the indexPath.row.
Add the button an action target to your viewController and in that method delete the row according to the tag of the sender.

Comment: So I wouldn't like to do swipe to delete or anything, just a plane button in a view controller. So when you click on a row, it takes you view controller and in that view controller I would like to have a button to delete